# any restrictions on transferring money from personal to business account

Tags: united-states, european-union, texas, limited-liability-company, wisconsin

I'm starting a company and was wondering if I can use the income from my day job to fund my company until things are up and running. Basically I'd transfer funds from my personal account to the company account which is then used for company related expenses. Is this legal in Texas or Wisconsin? is it illegal in your state? what about EU countries?

PS: I'm open as to where the entity resides so if there are territorial differences on how the capital is provided, then I'd take the territories that allow for using personal fund through the company account of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with this, legally speaking (as long as it's for legitimate uses and not trying to create a tax shelter). Just keep track of your contributions for tax purposes.

Comment: Thanks! when paying taxes for entity, myself or both? I'm new to this.

Comment: Both/any, how you do it depends on what type of legal business structure you've set up.